# Get Package XML from SSIS Catalog with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, ssis

Is there a way to get the Package XML from the packages that are in the SSIS Catalog with PowerShell, but without downloading and extracting the project? I want to search for certain strings within the XML document.

```
################################
########## PARAMETERS ##########
################################ 
$SsisServer = ".\sql2016"



############################
########## SERVER ##########
############################
# Load the Integration Services Assembly
$SsisNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($SsisNamespace) | Out-Null;

# Create a connection to the server
$SqlConnectionstring = "Data Source=" + $SsisServer + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $SqlConnectionstring

# Create the Integration Services object
$IntegrationServices = New-Object $SsisNamespace".IntegrationServices" $SqlConnection

# Check if connection succeeded
if (-not $IntegrationServices)
{
    Throw [System.Exception] "Failed to connect to server $SsisServer "
}



#############################
########## CATALOG ##########
#############################
# Create object for SSISDB Catalog
$Catalog = $IntegrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

# Check if the SSISDB Catalog exists
if (-not $Catalog)
{
    Throw [System.Exception] "SSISDB catalog doesn't exist!"
}



##########################
########## LOOP ##########
##########################
foreach ($Folder in $Catalog.Folders)
{
    Write-Host $Folder.Name
    foreach ($Project in $Folder.Projects)
    {
        Write-Host " - " $Project.Name
        foreach ($Package in $Project.Packages)
        {
            Write-Host "    - " $Package.Name
            # HOW TO GET PACKAGE XML???

            # Not working:
            # Exception calling "Serialize" with "1" argument(s):
            # "The parameter 'sink.Action' is invalid."
            #$sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
            #$sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter($sb)
            #$writer = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($sw)
            #$xml = $Package.Serialize($writer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this isn't going to be as [simple as one might expect](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsserver/en-US/8f731299-951b-45d0-ae21-216c6a781609/export-integration-services-catalogs-project-using-powershell?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 6):

Albeit the thread being a few months old, I believe the below approach directly answers the original question. I encountered a similar situation whereby I needed to access the XML from a package in SSISDB to serve as a template for new packages. Well, after reading the project bytes into my script,

```
var projectBytes = ssisServer.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders[SSISFolderName].Projects[SSISProjectName].GetProjectBytes();
```

it was possible to bypass downloading/unzipping by creating an in-memory archive from the project bytes. By iterating through the archive entries until the correct package was found (easier if the index of the file is known), the last step was to read the archive entry into a stream and pass it to the package.LoadFromXML method.

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(projectBytes);

ZipArchive za = new ZipArchive(stream);

foreach (ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry in za.Entries)
{
    if (zipEntry.FullName == SSISPackageName)
    {
         Package pkg = new Package();

         StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(zipEntry.Open());

         pkg.LoadFromXML(sr.ReadToEnd(), null);

         break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had no luck trying a pure object model version of this code as I was getting the [error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsserver/en-US/8f731299-951b-45d0-ae21-216c6a781609/export-integration-services-catalogs-project-using-powershell?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

> Exception calling "Serialize" with "1" argument(s): "The parameter 'sink.Action' is invalid."

Super! After doinking around for an hour trying to get to the project via the Managed Object Model, I gave up and went the TSQL route. We simply need to emulate the call to `SSISDB.catalog.get_project` and pass it the folder and project names

```
Function Get-ProjectsTsql
{
    param
    (
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder] $folder
    ,   [string] $serverName = "localhost\dev2016"
    )

    # we want to build an execute procedure call that looks like this
    # exec [SSISDB].[catalog].[get_project] @folder_name=N'FolderName',@project_name=N'ProjectName'

    $connectionString = [String]::Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;", $serverName)
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $integrationServices = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices($connection)
    # The one, the only SSISDB catalog
    $catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

    #Instance of ProjectInfo
    foreach ($proj in $folder.Projects)
    {
        $projName = $proj.Name
        $folderName = $folder.Name

        $zipOut = "C:\tmp\$projName.zip"

        $query = "exec [SSISDB].[catalog].[get_project] @folder_name=N'$folderName',@project_name=N'$projName'"
        # Write-Host $query

        $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $command.CommandText = $query
        $command.Connection = $connection
        $projectBinary = $command.ExecuteScalar()
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($zipOut,$projectBinary)
    }
}

Function Get-CatalogFolders
{
    param
    (
        [string] $serverName = "localhost\dev2012"
    )

    $connectionString = [String]::Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;", $serverName)

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

    $integrationServices = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices($connection)
    # The one, the only SSISDB catalog
    $catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

    $catalogFolders = $catalog.Folders

    return $catalogFolders
}

$serverName = "localhost\dev2016"
# Identify all the folders on the server
foreach ($folder in Get-CatalogFolders $serverName)
{
    # Save out all the projects to their zip files
    Get-ProjectsTsql $folder $serverName
}
```

This gets the ispac which I save with a .zip extension (because it's just a zip). To get the package xml, you then need to unzip the file, find your package and go from there

Comment: Thanks, got the same error when using Serialize :-(
          
The download and unzipping workaround, which is was trying to avoid, is also possible without TSQL by using: $Project.GetProjectBytes() (see: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2016/04/get-packages-from-ssis-catalog.html)

Comment: I should have figured you'd have a post on it ;) You in Redmond this week? If not, I can flag down the SSIS team, see if they have any insight on the error

Comment: Yes will be in Redmond this week. Lets try and see if the SSIS team has a solution for this. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Got an answer: not possible without downloading because they don't store individual packages in the catalog

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to read data in the package and get the xml directly, then it seems the XML code of the packages are actually stored as Binary data in the object_data column of the SSISDB.internal.object_versions table.ref.[1]

You can use **[GetSqlBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlbinary.aspx)** method to retrieve this data. I have seen an example of this used to retrieve SSRS rdl files. See ref.[2] for a full example of the code.

```
    # New BinaryWriter; existing file will be overwritten. 
    $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($name), Create, Write; 
    $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($fs); 

    # Read of complete Blob with GetSqlBinary 
    $bt = $rd.GetSqlBinary(2).Value; 
    $bw.Write($bt, 0, $bt.Length); 
    $bw.Flush(); 
    $bw.Close(); 
    $fs.Close();
```

***References***

1. [msdn forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a5bc2a2-cdb8-422e-910b-cc01d4d116e2/ssisdb-project-deployment-where-is-the-physical-dtsx-file-stored-?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
2. [Export all SSRS Reports, DataSources and resources](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Export-of-all-SSRS-reports-57910227)

Comment: Hi sqlchow, thanks for the reply! The SSISDB.[internal].[object_versions] table contains the various versions of the project (ispac). You can join it to SSISDB.[internal].[projects] (on project_id = object_id). It contains the same data as $Project.GetProjectBytes() , but then also from all the previous project versions.