# Decrypt XML in SSISDB

Tags: xml, encryption, ssis

Our current packages are stored in msdb for deployment and we have a job that allows developers to determine what objects are used in what processes by querying an in-house developed job that populates this table.  This is a 2008 SSIS job.  We are in the process of converting this job to 2016 and that will use SSISDB to manage the package data.  As you know, SSISDB has the XML encrypted in the table.

I did search on SO and didn't find much (really didn't find much anywhere) on a successful decryption of the XML data using the function

```
internal.decrypt_binarydata() which takes: @algorithmName, @key, @IV, @binary_value
```

Has anyone successfully decrypted the XML data that is stored in SSISDB and if so, could you please share some code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msdb stores packages in dbo.sysssispackages (or sysdtspackages90 if you're still on 2005)

The SSISDB does not store packages. It stores .ispac files which contain Project level connection managers, the project parameter files, a manifest *and* packages. The ispac is just a zip file. It's stored in SSISDB.internal.object_versions.

To work with that data, you'll need to open the correct key(s) or impersonate a user that has that permission and then look at the approaches in [Get Package XML from SSIS Catalog with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439662/get-package-xml-from-ssis-catalog-with-powershell)

Comment: Are you aware of any other methods to work with the data instead of Powershell, such as .NET or t-SQL (if t-SQL, perhaps by calling the decrypt function above)?

Comment: The referenced PowerShell is just using the .NET framework libraries. Nothing PS specific in it except that it's gluing things together without the need for a custom .NET application. A cursory search on those libraries will find C#, VB.NET implementations but again if the intention is to run from a SQL Agent job, it has a custom job type for PowerShell. A pure TSQL implementation does not exist to my knowledge