# Search for a variable value in SSIS packages deployed in SSISDB integration Catalog

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I have several packages/projects deployed in the SSISDB catalog. I want to find which packages have a specific expression attached to a variable value. Is there a TSQL way of doing this? I know the package data is encrypted in `[internal].[packages]`. But with the proper credentials, is it possible to decrypt it? Or what are the other options I have? Can I use some C#/Powershell script to search?

Answer (score 1):

There is no tables that stores this kind of information. You should search for it by reading the package XML. Using SSISDB, it is **not possible to read the package XML using T-SQL** since SSISDB encrypts the whole project as binary.

To read the package's XML, you should extract the project binary using the `SSISDB.cataloag.get_project` stored procedure. Change the extract file extension to `.zip` and extract its content. Then, loop over packages to check if the variable is used in each package. This can be done using C# or PowerShell:

- [Extracting dtsx from Integration Service Catalog from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70978707/extracting-dtsx-from-integration-service-catalog-from-c-sharp/70991430#70991430)
- [Get Package XML from SSIS Catalog with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439662/get-package-xml-from-ssis-catalog-with-powershell)

In case you are storing the database within SQL Server *(Msdb)* you can read the package XML data from the  `msdb.dbo.sysssispackages` table.